# Access request to account by com.eg.android.AlipayGphone.perf

Tags: samsung, security, permissions, android-11, accounts

The message below keeps popping up.

> [image: Screenshot or message]
>
> #### Access request
>
> The following one or more apps request permission to access your account, now and in the future.
>
> - **Alipay**
>   com.eg.android.AlipayGphone.perf
>
> Do you want to allow this request?

*How do I find out which account Alipay wants access to?*

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy A22.

Comment: Which Android version is this? is it Oreo 8.0?

Comment: @M.A. Android version: 11

Comment: Maybe it's related to how Alipay handles account access to sync data.Try contacting AliPay via their support page: https://global.alipay.com/docs/ac/ams_oc/support

Comment: As a general rule: do not grant access to any app you do not know what it is doing.